# Фоновое изображение для текстуры текста

Tags: html, css

Как сделать цвет шрифта из картинки "камуфляжный стиль" на темном фоне?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Мне пришло только в голову навешивать png или svg изображение с камуфляжем поверх текста.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте CSS-свойство [`-webkit-background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) со значением *text* :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Emblema+One&display=swap');

body { background: #010111; }

.clip {
  font: 18vw/90vh 'Emblema One', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0 / cover url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzhCf.png');
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px yellow);
}

.clip::before, .clip::after { content: '\2606'; text-shadow: 0 0 2px red; }
```

```html
<div class="clip">ARMOR</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!! Выручили)))